# Query Custom Post Type based on text input

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I want to query the custom post type by the three fields below.  The two select fields and the one text field.  The text field is the one that is not working currently.

What is wrong? How can I fix that?

```
        <form name="search" action="" method="get">

            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <select name="city" style="width:175px;" >
            <?php
            $cities = mo_baptist_get_meta('street_city');
            if ($cities) {
                foreach ($cities as $city) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $city . "\">" . $city . "</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            <label for="association">Association:</label>
            <select name="association" style="width:175px;">
            <?php
            $associations = mo_baptist_get_meta('association');
            if ($associations) {
                foreach ($associations as $association) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $association . "\">" . $association . "</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php $zip_code = mo_baptist_get_meta('street_zip'); ?>"

            <input type="submit" value="search" />
        </form>
        <?php $az = range('a', 'z');


        ?>

      <table>
          <colgroup>
            <col width="300">
            <col width="200">
            <col />
            <col />
          </colgroup>

          <thead>
            <th><?php _e('Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('City'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('Phone'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('Website'); ?></th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <?php $zip_code = $_GET['street_zip']; $cities = $_GET['city'];  $associations = $_GET['association']; 
            if ($cities  || $associations  || $zip_code) {
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args=array(
                'post_type'  =>  'church',
                'order'  => 'ASC',
                'orderby'  => 'title',
                'posts_per_page'  => 25,
                'paged'=>$paged,
                'meta_query'  =>  array(
                    array(
                        'value'  =>  $cities,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value'  =>  $associations,
                    ), 
                    array(
                        'value'  =>  $zip_code,
                    )
                )
              );
              query_posts($args);
            } else {
             query_posts(array(
                'post_type'  =>  'church',
                'order'  => 'ASC',
                'orderby'  => 'title',
                'posts_per_page'  => 25,
                'paged'  =>  $paged
            )); } if (have_posts()): while (have_posts($paged)): the_post(); $church = get_post_custom($post->ID); ?>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="church-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $church['street_city'][0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $church['phone'][0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php if (!empty($church['website_url'][0])): ?><a href="http://<?php echo $church['website_url'][0]; ?>"><?php _e('Homepage') ?></a><?php endif; ?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="search-pagination">

          <?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>

        </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is pre-populate the text input, it looks to me like you need to echo the $zip_code variable you are creating:

```
<input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php $zip_code = mo_baptist_get_meta('street_zip'); echo $zip_code ?>" />
```

other than that, I also noticed that the text input was not closed - I added that in the above example...